# Identifying memory leaks in a Java-based application that replicates CDC changes from PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, memory-leaks

I have Java-based application, where the main objective is to read CDC (Change Data Capture) changes from a source PostgreSQL database using the `libpq.c` library and replicate those changes to a target PostgreSQL database using JDBC.

However, in the production environment running on Ubuntu 20, the application consumes a significant amount of memory, specifically 13 GB out of 16GB, as observed through the `htop` command. Surprisingly, when I utilize Java profiler tools such as VisualVM and JDK Mission Control, I notice that the application only holds around 1 GB of memory or even less.

Now I'm wondering how to pinpoint the exact location of the memory leaks. Although I am uncertain, I suspect that the issue may not lie within the `libpq.c` library.

Comment: Do not tag C++ when your question is about java

Comment: If this is Unix, use `ps` or `top` to show which process consumes the memory.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe using `top` its consuming 80% of memory.

Comment: You are saying "it". What? The PostgreSQL server? Your Java program? If the latter, you have to debug your code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Well basically the reading unit that is capturing the CDC from database is written in C++ that's why there would be the probability memory leaks in that area.

Comment: But we can't see that code, so it is not important to your question. And libpq.c looks more like a "C" library to me... anyway to ask a question about programming here it is customary to also show a minimal reproducible example that shows your problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have already debug my Java program, and I don't see any possible case, where the memory leaks arise. As I mentioned earlier , I have also used Java profiler tools but didn't find any corner case.

Comment: @PepijnKramer you are right. Is there any way how to spot the issue, from Java end, I didn't see problem. Any idea would be much appreciated. 
Our C code is much similar to the following : 

https://gist.github.com/ictlyh/12fe787ec265b33fd7e4b0bd08bc27cb

Comment: I don't really have any java experience. I have some experience with .Net and C++. The trick is to force the garbage collected language to free up memory (early) on the ("C" or "C++") heap when done. So instead of relying on garbage collection you do (manual) resource management. No idea if that is your case but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: Another way around this is to copy data from your the "C" library to your java code and then immediately release the memory returned by the "C" code. So you keep the interaction between technologies very local, if will be safe but copying might also be too much of a performance issue.